# How to invoke a pipeline with parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I've created several pipelines with parameters, I'd like to test their behavior with different sets of parameters, how can I do this in Python? I've found an answer to do this in Powershell but not on Python.

I tried browsing the Python Data Factory sdk but I dont know if the issue is I'm not familiar with Python or if the sdk is not very intuitive.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of posting the code here, I've created a GitHub Gist to show 2 different ways to login and call pipelines with whatever parameters you need.

Here you go: https://gist.github.com/Gorgoras/1fe534fd9b454412f81c8203c773c483

Hope this helped!!

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks a lot. The script is failing me on the first line, does it need any library other than data factory?

Comment: Thats weird, do you have all the Azure libraries? If not, you might be missing the credentials part of it. Try "pip install azure-common"

Comment: It didnt work but I ended up doing pip install azure and now it works!! Thanks a lot

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help